# Showing images in subcategories in opencart

Tags: php, image, opencart

Recently I installed Opencart 1.5.6 for the first time. Everything in ok except that I trying to show images along with text in sub-categories ( where is Refine Search text ).
So far I've put this in `catalog\controller\module\category.php`

```
$children_data[] = array(
    'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
    'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
    'image'       => $category['image'],
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
);      
}

$this->data['categories'][] = array(
    'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
    'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $total . ')' : ''),
    'image'       => $category['image'],
    'children'    => $children_data,
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
);
```

New thing is `'image' => $category['image'],`. I also change a little bit `catalog\view\theme\MYTHEME\template\product\category.tpl` like this:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>

  <li>
      <img src="../../../../../../image/data/models/<?php echo $category['image']; ?>" width="100"/>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
  </li>

  <?php } ?>
</ul>
<ul>
  <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($categories) / 4); ?>
  <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
  <?php if (isset($categories[$i])) { ?>
  <li>
      <img src="../../../../../../image/data/models/<?php echo $categories['image']; ?>" width="100"/>
      <a href="<?php echo $categories[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $categories[$i]['name']; ?></a></li>

    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The result is box with broken image and text under the image. [image: This]

I can see from error what is it but can't figure out how to repair it
`<img src="../../../../../../image/data/models/<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: image in <b>..\catalog\view\theme\mytheme\template\product\category.tpl</b> on line <b>29</b>" width="100"/>`

Comment: Everything looks fine except that in the HTML do not put `../../../../../../image/data/models/` before the image as it contains the correct path already... It should only be `<img src="<?php echo $categories[$i]['image']; ?>" width="100"/>`. Also mind that you are calling `<?php echo $categories['image']; ?>` whereas it has to be **`<?php echo $categories[$i]['image']; ?>`**.

Comment: Still same but this time `Notice: Undefined variable: i ...` and no images.

Comment: It looks like you have mistyped the `for-loop`: `<?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>` should be <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, this was wrong also and I corrected(Thank you for this) it but still with this error `Notice: Undefined variable: i ...` and no images. On this line is Notice - `<img src="<?php echo $categories[$i]['image']; ?>" width="100"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like in default OpenCart code.

## Step 1

Open file `catalog/view/theme/<your theme>/template/template/category.tpl`

**Find** : Refine Category code.

**Add after** `<div class="category-list">` start div

```
<?php $counter = 0; foreach ($categories as $category) {?>  
            <div>
                <?php if ($category['thumb']) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="image/no_image.jpg" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
            </div>
    <?php $counter++; } ?>
```

## Step 2

Open file `catalog/controller/product/category.php`

**Find** :

```
$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
```

**Add after**

```
$image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height'));
```

## Step 3

In the same file `catalog/controller/product/category.php`

**Find** :

```
'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
```

**Replace** (instead of above line)

```
'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url), 'thumb' => $image
```

and then check it.

Comment: Hey, thank's for that but unfortunately I get this Notice and no image `Notice: Undefined index: thumb in ... category.tpl line 26` which is `<?php if ($category['thumb']) { ?>`

Comment: Hi, I think, You need to follow properly Step 3. Step3 code is Replace code instead of Find line code. & also, When you are not add category image. So, will display no image thumb. & You will add category image from admin side. So, it will category image display there.

Comment: So, I've been editing wrong file all the time thats why it didn't work. I've been editing `controller/module/category.php` instead of `controller/product/category.php`. After editing correct file now is working perfectly. Thank's for your help!