# OpenCart - show SubCategory images ($thumb) on Category page

Tags: php, opencart

Version 1.5.6.4;

If a category has subcategories, I want to show as a heading - grid of subcategory images. Instead of class="category-head" and class="category-list". If there is no subcategories should display one specific image for each category.

Now, what I need is a variable on category page that holds a links to subcategory images. I have $thumb which has a link to category image (I am using it for 'no subcategories' option).
I've solved this using fixed links to subcategory images, but now it would be good to have this dynamically.

[edit] Here is the code if there is sub-catagories:

```
<div class="category-grid">
<?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($categories);) { ?>
<ul>
  <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($categories) / 4); ?>
  <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
  <?php if (isset($categories[$i])) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $categories[$i]['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $categories[$i]['name']; ?>" />
  </a>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I used original code with minor alterations. It shows category thumbnails as a grid - one same image for each sub-category. It should shows sub-category thumbnails. So I'm afraid this goes down to Controller.[/edit]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your question fits this description of *off-topic* questins: *3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*, according to [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @shadyyx I am not sure what you consider as a 'homework', but if the question is unclear, I could update it with code snippets. I thought this is a common problem so I kept it simple: _category/$thumb_ is passed to category page, I need _subcategory/$thumb[ ]_

Comment: Code snippets from OpenCart are useless. Anybody working with OpenCart has the whole source code available, besides that source code for OpenCart could be found on GitHub. We are interested in your code, what have you tried/done to achieve your goal and where the difficulties you encounter are...

Comment: I think, You need to read this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652988/showing-images-in-subcategories-in-opencart/24654452#24654452