# Add alternate category thumbnail for refine search

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart2.x

Opencart categories out of the box can each have one image associated with it. I would like to have the ability to associate a second image with each category.

The first thing I did was show the category image in the refine search box.

Next I created a thumbnail_image column to the category field in the database.

I am having difficulty getting the new image field to show on the page I have edited the controller and template file to no avail it just shows as an empty box.

Here is a link to the page to hopefully clarify my intentions.

http://sarasotasalonequipment.com/commerce/index.php?route=product/category&path=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing images in subcategories in opencart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652988/showing-images-in-subcategories-in-opencart)

Comment: No that post is using the already default category image, which is used in several places on the website. I am trying to add a second image to be associated with each category.